# What is the purpose of a list of value context variable in Talend?

Tags: talend

What is the purpose of a List of Value context variable  in a Talend Job?

I can't seem to make any use of it as a store for multiple values for a variable.

When I access the context variable from a tJava component or event when I just dump the context to the console log all I see is the first value in the list.

What are some good patterns for using a list of value context variable in Talend?

Answer (score 2):

I find the List Of Value useful if I want to prompt the user to pick a item from a list, to do that, just check the 'prompt' box of your context var.

Comment: Which doesn't work when scheduling it in TAC :( It would be nice if we could have that dropdown there as well.